# WinUI3 : How to close a WinUI3 window without stopping the event loop

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winui-3, c++-winrt, windows-app-sdk

I'm working on a WinUI3 desktop application in C++. I'm trying to build a multiwindow application that will be still running and accepting events even when all the Windows are closed.
In WinUI3, the event loop(Application::Start()) will terminate when the last window is closed. I was not able to find any way to keep the WinUI3 event loop running when all the windows are closed.

But I was able to achieve it in one way, i.e I extracted the HWnd from the WinUI3 window and subclassed it, And handled WM_DESTROY message like this.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK
MyWindowClass::WindowSubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT messageCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (messageCode)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        // PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
```

This stopped the event loop to terminate as I didn't do `PostQuitMessage(0);`
Then when I actually needed the application to terminate, I called `PostQuitMessage(0);` to stop the event loop and close the application.

As this is one work around I could think of, is there any better way to achieve it?

I would be of great help if you could help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: With [an invisible new window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window#show-a-new-window)([AppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.windowmanagement.appwindow?view=winrt-22621))?

Comment: Thank you for the response @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, In that case, we will have an invisible window instance which will be only used to keep the event loop running, and we will close it[along with all other windows] when we want the app to end. Is there any other way instead of having a separate Window instance to do it?

Comment: You can vote on or suggest features on WindowsAppSDK [productboard portal](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK#contributing).